# Resizing the map item in QGIS print composer without changing scale?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, print-composer

Is it possible to lock the scale in the QGIS 2.0.1 print composer? Every time I resize the map, the scale is adjusted. This makes trying out different map layouts really annoying.

Comment: What do you mean with "resize the map"?

Comment: In the print composer I can change the size of the map on the page. If the page is A4-format I can make it the size of the page or leave a border. When I do this the scale always changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function was not added to QGIS until version 2.2, so it's a surprisingly recent development. In the most recent version the print composer behaves a little bit more like what we're used to with graphics editors - simply hold shift while you resize your map frame.

If it's a great inconvenience you can upgrade, otherwise you'll have to deal with this frustration. [Here](http://nyalldawson.net/2013/10/waiting-for-qgis-2-2-composer-improvements-part-1/) is a blog post that provides an overview of print composer improvements in 2.2, as well as a list of additions slated for future releases.

Comment: "Holding shift while resizing items locks their aspect ratio" not the scale.

Answer (score 20):

**Update 27/07/2018: As of QGIS 3.2.1, my workaround below no longer works!** If I find an alternative solution I will post here again. This is very, very annoying...

---

There is a way to do this.

- In the Item properties tab for your map item, click on the black-and-yellow "data defined override" icon to the right of the "scale" box.
- Click on "Edit".
- In the "Expression" box, type your desired scale (for example, 50000) and hit OK.

The item's scale will now be fixed at 1:50000 and will remain so no matter how much you move or resize it.

[Jyler's suggestion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/77022) simply doesn't work (QGIS 2.6.0 Brighton) while I can only assume that [Ardit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/77028) either has the world's fastest PC and/or only works on very simple maps with a handful of layers. The automatic rescaling "feature" is incredibly annoying and I cannot imagine why the developers thought it was a good idea.

Comment: Your solution continues to work in 3.8 and 3.4 though so that may have been a temporary bug.

Comment: I can confirm this solution works in 3.10 and 3.12 as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can type in the desired scale manually in the scale text box every time you change the paper size.  This can be done in a split of a second and I wouldn't call it annoying as far as you don't change the paper size let's say more than 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in 3.0.2 by setting the 'unit' dropdown menu in the Symbol Style options panel to "meters at scale".

Answer (score 0):

I was looking how to do this today. If you're happy with the scale and the position of the upper-left corner of your map, then you can copy and paste your Scale, X min and Y max values as data-defined values.