# QGIS 3.16 - I want to make by 6"x9" map a 24x36, but all of the text/layers are tiny. Is it possible to automatically scale all of the layers?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, cartography, scale, mapping

I recently got a freelancing gig and am really excited, but I'm having troubles exporting my map in a different size in QGIS. My client wants a map sized 24"x36", and I have created one that's 6"x9". However, when I go to page properties and change it to 24x36, and drag the map content to fit, the labels and the text are minuscule (I assume 4x smaller).

Is there a way to resize all of the layers ala resizing a jpg in word?  I would think with vectors this would be pretty straightforward. I understand there is a way to do units in map units, but it seems like a big timesink.

6x9 map
[image]

24x36 map
[image]

Comment: Have you tried this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77018/resizing-the-map-item-in-qgis-print-composer-without-changing-scale

Comment: No, that didn't work - I am not trying to keep the scale of the map consistent, I am tryiing to keep the font and layers the same size relative to the size of the map.  Aka if I am making a map 4x bigger, I want the width of the line layers and text to become 4x bigger as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution in post-processing the QGIS output pdf is probably your best quick'n'dirty solution.

QGIS carefully keeps track whether label font sizes, line widths, etc., are specified in map units or in image units (mm, points, etc.). So your e.g. 1mm line which looks great in 6x9 will be too small if looked at from a reasonable viewing distance for 24x36.

It is somewhat painstaking, but where I have built maps which I knew were going to be outputted in different "form factors" and read by users from different visual distances, I have used expressions with variables to help.

1. Define a variable `symb_scale` with value `'1'` in `Project / Project properties / Variables`.
2. In your layer symbology (and labeling formating), wherever you specify a fixed size, e.g. 0.66 (mm thick line) or 10 (pt font), instead do a data-defined over-ride with expression `0.66*@symb_scale` (etc.) Make the sizes look good on the map canvas and/or your default layout.
3. In additional, special layouts, like your large poster, over-ride the scaling by redefining `symb_scale` as a **layout** variable with a different scaling factor, say `'3'`. You do this under `Layout / Properties` with the variable panel being way down at the bottom of the right-hand panel. The expressions in 2. will now mean that within this layout, all lines / fonts will be 3x as large. You can set the factor differently for different layouts. For instance, a poster map (to be read at large distance), a 11x17 map (to be read close up, with lots of detail), and an offline MBTiles map loaded onto pocket devices with a wacky scaling factor.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for now, in case anyone stumbles on this. I exported the 6x9 pdf to illustrator, and then resized the artboard to my desired size of 24x36, and then selected all of my layers to expand them to the new artboard's size.

Still, I want to be able to do this in QGIS!